# Emergency Mode, Can't Log In

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uuid

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox, and I have been trying to move my home directory to a different partition today.

Now, I can no longer log in. As it starts booting up, it goes through the standard process before kicking me back to 'Emergency Mode', which prompts me to either log in as root and check the logs, restart, or attempt to continue.

Continuing brings me back to the same issue, as does restart.

I ran journalctl -xb as prompted, and the only two lines that stood out in red were the following:

kernel: intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0

and

systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-e559f076

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and VirtualBox, what can I do to fix this (or find a deeper error to look into)?

Comment: In the `terminal`, or in emergency mode root access, show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo fdisk -l` and `lsblk`and I'll take a look for you. Ping me at `@heynnema` in a comment when you have this info.

Answer (score 0):

`systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-e559f076`

this is the error. you have to edit /etc/fstab and fix the uuid of this drive.
8 digits means it is a fat formated drive.

Answer (score 0):

You already have two excellent directions from heynnema & ravery.

I should add that this probably happened because you changed your shared folders on virtualbox settings? It may be easier to first provide your root password when it asks for it, then edit the /etc/fstab file (editor /usr/bin/nano should be friendly enough, or you might want to use vi), and comment out the line that mentions your dev-disk-by\x2dpartuuid-e559f076 by adding a # at the beginning of the line.

Then exit the shell which should cause reboot or type reboot then when your linux is up you reconfigure your virtual-box shared folders, and I believe virtualbox should take care of adjusting your /etc/fstab file afterwards.